# How to add two functional components in a row in class component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add two functional components in a [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLlej.png)class component in a row using flexbox but it squeezes the size

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please update the question to include actual code which demonstrates the problem.  If the problem is indeed just the CSS styling then this would have little or nothing to do with ReactJS and can be demonstrated with simply HTML/CSS.  Please include a runnable code snippet which shows the problem and describe what result you were expecting and why.  For tips and information about asking a question, please see [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: This is not clear

Answer (score 0):

use `flex-shrink:0` in children of flex to prevent squeezing.